# grep pattern syntax

Tags: grep, xargs, pcregrep

i have a file with names which i make with three files.
i want grep 0 if the pattern is absent from any file and 1 if the pattern is present i am using this command

```
cat X.nam |xargs -i grep -c -P '{}$' A.nam > a
```

i am getting this error

```
grep nothing to repeat

X.nam
A
AADLGS
AAEGVG
AAGVGTWP
AASLSSIT
AASLSSVN
AASLTGCN
ACL*AML
ACLSGSA
ACL*VVM
A.nam
AAGVGTWP
AASLSSIT
AASLSSVN
AASLTGCN
ACL*AML
ACLSGSA
```

Comment: I don't think that's a problem with your grep *syntax* per se; it's just grep (when in PCRE mode) telling you that one of your patterns contains a quantifier without a preceding regex atom (as you can demonstrate using `grep -P '*foo' somefile` for example)

Comment: Is there a line in `X.nam` that begins with `*` or `+`? That would cause this error.

Comment: Do you understand that the lines you're substituting from `X.nam` will be treated as regular expressions, not matched literally? So `ACL*AML` will match `ACAML`, `ACLLAML`, ACLLLLLLLML`, etc.?

Comment: no i want them to match literally

Answer (score 1):

That error means you have a quantifier like `*` or `+` with nothing before it.

I suspect you don't want the words in `X.nam` to be treated as regular expressions, they should be matched literally. In PCRE, you can enclose parts of the pattern in `\Q` and `\E` to quote them.

```
cat X.nam |xargs -i grep -c -P '\Q{}\E$' A.nam > a
```

Comment: what does \Q and |E stands for

Comment: They stand for quote and end

Comment: ohk thank you. i am trying this hope it will work

Comment: thank you so much Barmur. it works. I am really obliged. i just added x with c                                                                                                                   
  cat X.nam |xargs -i grep -cx -P '\Q{}\E$' A.nam > a                                     
 is it ok